# vb.net append an empty tag with format <DATA />

Tags: xml, vb.net, tags, append

I have an Xml file which is created by my vb.net app if its not found the code for this is as follows:

```
  If Not System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\XML\DATA.xml") Then
            Dim myWriter As New XmlTextWriter((Application.StartupPath & "\XML\DATA.xml"), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            myWriter.WriteStartDocument(True)
            myWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            myWriter.Indentation = 2

            myWriter.WriteStartElement("ID")

            myWriter.WriteEndDocument()
            myWriter.Close()
```

This however creates tags that if no inner text is suplied that look like:

```
<DATA />
```

instead of

```
<DATA></DATA>
```

Which really dosen't bother me except now if i want to append the `<DATA />` tag as follows:

```
Dim myDocXml As New XmlDocument()
        myDocXml.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\XML\DATA.xml")

Dim myNode As XmlNode = myDocXml.SelectSingleNode(".//DATA/ID")

        If myNode IsNot Nothing Then
            myNode.ChildNodes(0).InnerText = TextBox1.Text
        Else
            myeNode.Item(0).InnerText = TextBox1.Text
        End If

mysDocXml.Save(Application.StartupPath & "\XML\DATA.xml")
```

In which case I now get promted when debugging that the Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

how do I append such a tag format?

Comment: According to the xml specification the closing tag does not require the tag name.  So <DATA /> is acceptable.  The specification also allows for both the closing tag to be part of the open tag or the closing tag to be in a separate element.

Comment: Well then I  confused to where the object reference not set to an instance of an object. error comes from along side the fact that if I change the tag from <DATA /> to <DATA></DATA> it dose work?

Comment: The exception is due to myNode.ChildNodes(0) is null.

Comment: I tried setting it to the nodes name "DATA" but then it stalled whilst debugging saying that it wasnt an integer, which leaves me to belive that the 0 references to the number of nodes after the "DATA" node thus being the first one its 0 ???? I have one child node before that one which works fine???